I'm having trouble importing class variable "i" from class "Delivery" to class "CustomerScript"
Delivery.cs
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Impl;

public class Delivery : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int i = 0;
    public Kachinka Cash = new Kachinka();
    public int Sccore = 0;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Delivery)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collided with something..");

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Delivery)
    {
        if (Delivery.tag == "Stone")
        {

            Debug.Log("Triggered!!!");
            i = 1;
            Destroy(Delivery.gameObject);
            ;
        }

        if (Delivery.tag == "EditorOnly")
        {
            Sccore += 1;
            Debug.Log("Score: 1");
            Destroy(Delivery.gameObject);
        }
    }
}

I want to import and return "i = 1" from this file.
CustomerScript.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Delivery abc = new Delivery();

    void Update()
    {
        if (abc.i == 1)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(8.22f, 16.52f, -16f);
        }
    }
}

I wanted to use that updated value in CustomerScript.
Delivery.cs is attached to a RigidBody2D(Player with camera on it) and a BoxCollider2D and CustomerScript is attached to a sprite with a BoxCollider2D.
I tried updating the value of class variable 'i' in Delivery.cs and use that updated value to trigger a change in the position of an element using script CustomerScript. I wanted the Update() method to run without error but it wasn't executed.
I am new to C# and Game Dev so I've been stuck on this for quite some time now. Please ask for more info if I haven't made myself clear enough:)

when your Update-function isn't executed, this doesn't have anything to do with your field i being known to your script or not (public fields should be avoided, btw. Chose a property instead and a better name than just i). So start using your debugger and see if the function is executed or not.

Why are you using Delivery abc = new Delivery();? You never want to use new on MonoBehaviour scripts .. you rather want to either use GetComponent (or one of its variations) or reference an instance via the inspector .... [SerializeField] Delibery abc; and via the Inspector drag in the according object ... alternatively use void Start() { abc = FindAnyObjectByType<Delivery>(); assuming of course such component exists in your scene at all ...

Yea, I corrected it. thank you soo much!
